# How can I get Spring managed beans working with Jersey JUnit Tests?

Tags: spring, junit, jersey

The following isn't working:

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(MySpringConfigBean.class).
            register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.class);
}
```

I have a Spring config bean that defines a Jersey REST provider bean plus other supporting beans. How do I get this working?

This is with Jersey 2.4.1